# Is it possible to get the list of active profiles in Maven?

Tags: maven

In Maven, is there a way to get a list of the active profiles, say, as a property or as a text file?

More specifically, when I run:

```
mvn resources:resources -P MyProfile
```

I want to get the string `MyProfile` somewhere I can read it into my Java program.

Maven 3.2.1

Thanks

**Edit**

I attempted to configure the Maven Help plugin to run the `active-profiles` goal whenever the goal `resources:resources` is run by configuring an `execution` to participate in the `process-resources` [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Setting_Up_Your_Project_to_Use_the_Build_Lifecycle) as shown below. That did not work either ...:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- ... -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <output>${basedir}/target/active-profiles.txt</output>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/active-profiles-mojo.html) maven plugin. The configuration below will create a **text** file that will contain the profiles that were active during the build.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <output>${basedir}/target/active-profiles.txt</output>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I could not quite get it to work the way I wanted. I added the plugin definition to my `pom.xml`, ran `mvn resources:resources -P MyProfile`, and the `.txt` file did not show up. 

It did show up when I explicitly added the goal `help:active-profiles`. How can I get the `.txt` file without having to specify the extra goal?

Comment: resources:resources is a goal of the resources plugin. Therefore, executing mvn resources:resources will not execute goals of other plugins. If you don't want to define all the goals explicitly in every execution, you could bind the execution of the goals you want to run in a lifecycle phase ([this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) describes how).

Comment: I attempted to configure the Maven Help plugin to run the `active-profiles` goal as part of the `process-resources` phase and that did not work either. Please, see my new edits on the original question. Thanks.